# Can't format disk with mkfs command on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, fdisk

Followed this guide to add a new disk:

https://www.tecmint.com/add-new-disk-to-an-existing-linux/

That's become `/dev/sdb`.

After run `fdisk /dev/sdb` to do the partition. Check again:

```
fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 10.7 GB, 10737418240 bytes, 20971520 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O サイズ (最小 / 推奨): 512 バイト / 512 バイト
Disk label type: dos
ディスク識別子: 0x000cd479

デバイス ブート      始点        終点     ブロック   Id  システム
/dev/sda1   *        2048     2099199     1048576   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         2099200    20971519     9436160   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/cl-root: 8585 MB, 8585740288 bytes, 16769024 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O サイズ (最小 / 推奨): 512 バイト / 512 バイト


Disk /dev/mapper/cl-swap: 1073 MB, 1073741824 bytes, 2097152 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O サイズ (最小 / 推奨): 512 バイト / 512 バイト


Disk /dev/sdb: 2147 MB, 2147483648 bytes, 4194304 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O サイズ (最小 / 推奨): 512 バイト / 512 バイト
Disk label type: dos
ディスク識別子: 0xa267f022

デバイス ブート      始点        終点     ブロック   Id  システム
/dev/sdb1            2048     4194303     2096128   83  Linux
```

The `Device boot` has `/dev/sdb1`.

But run `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1` to format it, got this error:

```
mke2fs 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
/dev/sdb1 is apparently in use by the system; will not make a filesystem here!
```

Why? Can't format it? I want to use `/dev/sdb`, but maybe first should format `/dev/sdb1`. Now can't.

---

## Edit

### Run `lsblk`

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0   10G  0 disk
├─sda1        8:1    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─sda2        8:2    0    9G  0 part
  ├─cl-root 253:0    0    8G  0 lvm  /
  └─cl-swap 253:1    0    1G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sdb           8:32   0   16G  0 disk
sr0          11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
drbd0       147:0    0    2G  0 disk
```

### Run `lsof /dev/sdb1`

Returned nothing.

### Run `ls -l /sys/class/block/sdb1/holders`

```
Total: 0
```

### Run `pvs`

```
PV         VG Fmt  Attr PSize PFree
/dev/sda2  cl lvm2 a--  9.00g    0
```

### Run `lvmdiskscan`

```
  /dev/cl/root [       8.00 GiB]
  /dev/sda1    [       1.00 GiB]
  /dev/cl/swap [       1.00 GiB]
  /dev/sda2    [       9.00 GiB] LVM physical volume
  /dev/sdb1    [       2.00 GiB]
  2 disks
  2 partitions
  0 LVM physical volume whole disks
  1 LVM physical volume
```

### Run `mount`

```
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,seclabel,size=931116k,nr_inodes=232779,mode=755)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,seclabel)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,seclabel,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,seclabel,mode=755)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,seclabel,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_prio,net_cls)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuacct,cpu)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,relatime)
/dev/mapper/cl-root on / type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota)
selinuxfs on /sys/fs/selinux type selinuxfs (rw,relatime)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=31,pgrp=1,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,seclabel)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime,seclabel)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota)
tmpfs on /run/user/0 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,seclabel,size=188416k,mode=700)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,relatime)
```

## Edit 2

### Run `mkfs.ext4 -F /dev/sdb1`

```
mke2fs 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
/dev/sdb1 is apparently in use by the system; will not make a filesystem here!
```

### Run `umount /dev/sdb1`

```
umount: /dev/sdb1: not mounted
```

---

## A resource

http://www.overclockers.com/forums/showthread.php/667317-Unable-to-format-drive-quot-is-apparently-in-use-by-the-system-quot

Comment: Please show `lsblk`, `lsof /dev/sdb1`, and `ls -l /sys/class/block/sdb1/holders`.

Comment: @sourcejedi I added the results of your commands to the question.

Comment: What is the result of `pvs`? Maybe `/dev/sdb1` is added as part of lvm?

Comment: @RomeoNinov Added the `pvs` command result at bellow.

Comment: @cloud_cloud, the only idea i get in mind is to force fs creation: `mkfs.ext4 -F /dev/sdb1`. But if this partition is really in use the command can mess a lot of things

Comment: @cloud_cloud if you are going to format the disk, make sure the partition `/dev/sdb1` is unmounted by `umount /dev/sdb1` then use e.g `parted /dev/sdb --script rm 1`. Create the partition again using `parted` command and format `/dev/sdb1` using `mkfs.xfs /dev/sdb1` or `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1`

Comment: @RomeoNinov I have run that command (`mkfs.ext4 -F /dev/sdb1`) and pasted the result to the bellow.

Comment: @val0x00ff I run your command (`umount /dev/sdb1`) and added the result to the bellow.

Comment: @RomeoNinov I also added result of command `lvmdiskscan`.

Comment: @cloud_cloud can you find anything using `lsof | grep /dev/sdb` ?

Comment: Just in case : what does `mount` say?

Comment: @schaiba Added `mount` command result. I didn't mount that partition.

Comment: @cloud_cloud. What do you mean by your statement "The Device boot has /dev/sdb1."?

Comment: @fpmurphy1 I have remove `/dev/sdb` and added a new one named `/dev/sdc`. Things went well.

Comment: Any idea why you had [dbrd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drbd) showing up on it?? It makes sense that accessing the underlying disk at the same time as DRBD would generally not be desirable.

Comment: @sourcejedi I am doing the drbd test now. So need to add a new hard disk and partition/format now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> $ lsblk
> NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
> ...
> sdb           8:16   0    2G  0 disk
> ├─sdb1        8:17   0    2G  0 part
> └─drbd0     147:0    0    2G  1 disk
> ...
> ```
>
> I am doing the drbd test now. So need to add a new hard disk and partition/format now.

You're doing it wrong then!

Never write to the underlying device (`sdb`) once you have created `drbd0`.  Write to `drbd0` instead.  This would also solve the problem in the question.

At this point I would destroy `drbd0` and re-create it.

Comment: What's meaning of this: `Never write to the underlying device (sdb1) once you have created drbd0.`? What `write` do you mean here?

Comment: Any write that mentions sdb*.   Use drbd0 or drbd0p* instead.  Except something like `hdparm` parameters, where you're changing something about the individual disk hardware options and drbd wouldn't know how to pass it on to all of the underlying disks anyway.

Comment: My `lsblk -a` likes this: https://serverfault.com/questions/863231/cant-run-drbdadm-up-with-drbd-8-4-on-centos-7-3 . See `Edit 2`. `drbd0` position is different from yours.

Comment: I am sorry. The question of this topic was created yesterday. Some information are not right. I updated the `lsblk` result on the topic.

Comment: @cloud_cloud you haven't updated fdisk either, so now your question is nonsense.  If this question doesn't involve drbd, then remove this new weird 2G drbd device that we can't see what the underlying device is (maybe by rebooting?), and include output from `lsblk`, `lsof /dev/sdb*`, and `ls -l /sys/class/block/sdb*/holders` (I don't know exactly what the last does, it's possible it's completely redundant with lsblk, but it sounds very promising to me).  If it does involve drbd, then you should include the details you know about how the drbd was set up.

Comment: @cloud_cloud other than `mkfs`, the other output is fairly redundant because lsblk shows both mounted filesystems, and the existence of LVM PVs.  Only if there was a PV on sdb - which there isn't - then we'd need to know the PV had been deactivated.

Comment: @cloud_cloud apologies welcome, this is very frustrating as you'd posted  elsewhere and already had a long explanation that what you were doing was wrong.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry. I have did lots of things to try to solve the problem. Now the problem have been finished. Along the ways, there came many kinds of issues what I don't know before. So confirmed each step when it can't ran rightly. Many thanks for all of you.